# How to delete the cookies when the tomcat server shuts down?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, cookies

I want to store cookies using jsp and java and What I want is that cookies should only get stored till the time the tomcat server is running and it should get expired as soon as tomcat server shuts down .I know cookies are browser dependent and not server dependent , so How can I do this ?Is there any way I can do this?
P.S. I am new to cookies part so don't know much about it.

Comment: You can't. As simple as that. But nothing prevents you from ignoring or deleting the old cookie once the server has restarted and a new request comes in with such an old cookie. What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you uses the session, which would behave as I just described?

Comment: do you shut the tomcat manually or it might stop working for some internal errors?

Comment: P.S. If you're new to cookies, how about you research them first. That's how you learn new things you know, not just asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: You absolutely cannot control the actions of a disconnected web browser with regards to it's storage of cookies upon your server shutting down.

Comment: @JackMoore both could be the reason of shutdown...I mean I am only interested in shutting down of tomcat not its causes..

Comment: Could you explain *why* do you need this? It seems that you are on a wrong way.

Comment: @cooljohny it is impossible then sorry for that, unless you keep a browser window open with a javascript function to check the cookies in a specific interval and remove them, however I believe that does not help you as you want them to be deleted once the tomcat is shut down.

Comment: @AlexR What I want is that the browser should remeber id and password when the tomcat is running as I don't want him to login again on same session of tomcat as It would result in running of a program in background and his logging again would make two instances of that program which would be a problem for me ...

Comment: It seems that deletion of cookies when the server starts again is the only option for me??

Comment: No. That is impossible as well. Just ignore cookies that are not relevant anymore. Or use the HTTP session, which will do that for you.

Comment: @cooljohny, the question is not why do you want to remember the data in cookie. The question is why do you want to remove the data when tomcat is restarted.

Comment: @AlexR Because when tomcat is again started I want the user to login again so that my program in background should run ...but when he login for second time then the program will be already running in background and I don't want two instances of my program so I want to use cookies for second time..but when apache tomcat is shutdown my backgroung program will stop and thus when user login after starting tomcat that program should start again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are stored at client side and can be removed

1. by calling API
2. Automatically when *session* is gone
3. Automatically when cookie is expired.

Cooke is not removed automatically when container (tomcat in your case) is restarted. And it is good. Just imagine that every time when Google performs some maintenance all users must authenticate again. BTW this is why I think that you are on a wrong way.

But anyway, the question is how can you solve the problem. 
The answer is that the simplest way is to use session cookie. Such cookie will be removed when session is removed that happens when

- session is expired
- container is restarted. (BUT to be on the safe side remove content of work directory located under your tomcat home when tomcat is down before you start it again. This is because tomcat persists sessions to make it possible to connect to the same session after restart.)

If these solutions are good for you, go for it.

If not, you can manage this programmatically. Every time your application is started create some kind of ID. For example this may be the server start time. Save this start time in cookie at client side. This cookie will be sent to server with each user request (together with all other cookies). Compare this id with one stored at server side and invalidate all cookies if these IDs are not equal.

This is possible, will work exactly as you explained, but again: I believe that you have an architecture problem. Try to ask other question where you explain your requirements (not cokies etc, - functional requirements), suggest your design and ask for advise how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can, however, use the Session to store whatever it is you think you need to store in the Cookies. Sessions go away when the server is stopped unless you do something to persist them.

Comment: sessions go away when server is stopped or when user exits application?

Comment: When either happens. Both will cause the session to go away.